# JQuery not setting 'textcontent' in version 1.7.1

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code which is setting the target, href & textcontent for an element in HTML, this was working perfectly fine in JQuery 1.4.1 & 1.5.1 but after updating to 1.7.1 it does not change the 'textcontent' property of the visible element, the href has been updated.

```
 $("#uriEmma").attr('textcontent', emmaUri);
 $("#uriEmma").attr('href', emmaUri);
 $("#uriEmma").attr('target', '_blank');
```

Any ideas why this might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) and proper casing: `textContent`. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/3KKet/1/)

From documentation:

> The difference between attributes and properties can be important in
>   specific situations. Before jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method sometimes
>   took property values into account when retrieving some attributes,
>   which could cause inconsistent behavior. As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop()
>   method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while
>   .attr() retrieves attributes.

Answer (score 1):

**`.prop( propertyName )`**

The difference between attributes and properties can be important in specific situations. **Before jQuery 1.6,** the `.attr()` method sometimes took property values into account when retrieving some attributes, which could cause inconsistent behavior. As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop() method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while `.attr()` retrieves attributes.

For example, `selectedIndex`, `tagName`, `nodeName`, `nodeType`, `ownerDocument`, `defaultChecked`, and `defaultSelected` should be retrieved and set with the `.prop()` method. **Prior to jQuery 1.6,** these properties were retrievable with the `.attr()` method, but this was not within the scope of attr. These do not have corresponding attributes and are only properties.

Answer (score 0):

`textContent` is a DOM property, and not a HTML attribute.

In older versions of jQuery, the `attr()` function would almost always map to a property if the string case was the same as a matching property on the elements.  This changed in jQuery 1.6 (as it rightly should have), so now `attr()` almost exclusively maps to `setAttribute` and the new function [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop) was introduced to set properties on wrapped elements.

Aside from using `prop()`, you'll also need to ensure your casing is correct.  JavaScript and DOM properties use camel casing and start with a lower case letter.  So you need to use `textContent`, rather than `textcontent`.

Here's a couple of ways you can set the property in jQuery 1.6+:

```
// Set the first element's `textContent`
$("#someEl")[0].textContent = "test";

// Set every element's textContent
$("#someEl").prop('textContent', "test");

// Set every element's text, mapping to innerText in older browsers:
$("#someEl").text("test");
```

*nb* if you want to support IE 8 and lower, you need to use [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/test) or have a suitable test for using `innerText` instead of `textContent`.